# Changing apps width setting to 810px has no effect whatsoever

Tags: facebook, width

I have updated a couple of my Facebook tab apps settings to 810px from the previous 520px. However, this appears to be having no effect at all. Content is still showing in a 520px box.

Example: http://www.facebook.com/the.nextmen/app_117587821636543

As I mentioned, this isn't only happening on one application. I have changed several and seen no changes.

Comment: Potentially silly question: the pages you're checking on have Timeline activated, right?

Comment: Yes, timeline activated on all.

Comment: Are you sure you've changed the page tab app settings for app 117587821636543 to be 810x wide? It's on the main settings page, under 'Page Tab' - as far as I can tell from our side (Facebook) that app is still using the default, smaller size tab

Comment: In timeline enabled pages, 520px tabs are centered, and once you change it to 810px, contents of your tab should move to left. Even if you increased the size of the tab, width of the actual content of the tab might be smaller. In this case your tab will move to left side of the page once you enable 810px width.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I found the answer (thanks @Igy for pointing me to the Advanced tab).

Click on the **Advanced** tab and set **Page Tab iframe** to Enabled.
That appears to fix it right up.

Interestingly, I do not even see this option on my other two Apps (the two which did not have this issue). I am not clear on why my apps have different options. All three of them are just some simple HTML rendering in an iframe.

*P.S. Sorry to make two answers. I'm new here and didn't want my previous post to be an answer at all, but the system would not allow me to post a comment.*